# POSIX semaphore: Why come the parent process acquire semaphore before child releases it?

Tags: c, linux, semaphore

```
#include <semaphore.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pfds[2];
    char buff[20];
    sem_t sem;

    sem_init(&sem, 1, 1);
    pipe(pfds);


    if (!fork()) {
        printf("Child: Waiting to acquire semaphore\n");
        sem_wait(&sem);
        printf("child acquires lock\n");
        sleep(5);
        write(pfds[1], "Hello", 6);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
        close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
        printf("child releases lock\n");
        sem_post(&sem);
    }
    else {
        printf("Parent: Waiting to acquire semaphore\n");
        sem_wait(&sem);
        printf("Parent acquires lock\n");
        read(pfds[0],buff,6); /* we don't need this */
        printf("Parent read: %s",buff);
        printf("parent releases lock\n");
        sem_post(&sem);
    }
    sem_destroy(&sem);
    return 0;
}
```

Above is a simple pipe i have created in which the child writes and the parent reads. I have put a semaphore variable initialized to 1, so that while the child writes, the parent should wait. 
A deliberate "sleep" is added so that to see, the parent process spinning "Parent: Waiting to acquire semaphore" is printed.

```
The expected sequence should be:
Child: Waiting to acquire semaphore
child acquires lock...(delay of 5 secs here)
child releases lock

Parent: Waiting to acquire semaphore
Parent acquires lock
Parent read..bla-bla
parent releases lock

However it happens:
[root@localhost interview]# ./a.out
Child: Waiting to acquire semaphore
child acquires lock
Parent: Waiting to acquire semaphore
Parent acquires lock -> NOTE: Parent acquires lock before child releases it
child releases lock
Parent read: Hello
parent releases lock
```

Question is: How come parent acquires lock while the child is delayed and still holding it, and not yet released the semaphore?

Also, is there any way to make sure, that the child always acquires semaphore first, since it should write to the pipe?

EDIT: Thanks to @jxh. Here is the modified code that works great (pasting for everyone's reference).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void)
{
    int pfds[2];
    char buff[20];


    sem_t *sem = mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                  MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    sem_init(sem, 1, 0);
    pipe(pfds);


    if (!fork()) {
        write(pfds[1], "Hello", 6);   /* make stdout same as pfds[1] */
        close(pfds[0]); /* we don't need this */
        printf("child releases semaphore\n");
        sem_post(sem);
    }
    else {
        printf("Parent: Waiting to acquire semaphore\n");
        sem_wait(sem);
        printf("Parent acquires lock\n");
        read(pfds[0],buff,6); /* we don't need this */
        printf("Parent read: %s\n",buff);
        printf("parent releases lock\n");
        sem_post(sem);
    }
    sem_destroy(sem);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a `fork()` there is no guarantee that the child runs before the parent, and I am pretty sure it is usually the parent process that continues execution on the OS scheduler after the `fork()`.

The semaphore has to be in shared memory, as suggested by VoidPointer and QWR, and is stated in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init):

> If *pshared* is nonzero, then the semaphore is shared between processes, and should be located in a region of shared memory (see `shm_open(3)`, `mmap(2)`, and `shmget(2))`.

You can allocate the semaphore in shared memory with `mmap()` like this:

```
sem_t *sem = mmap(0, sizeof(sem_t), PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE,
                  MAP_SHARED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
assert(sem != MAP_FAILED);
```

You have initialized your semaphore to `1`, which allows the first call to `sem_wait()` to succeed. In your code, both the parent and child try to call `sem_wait()` at the "same time", which means whoever gets there first will acquire it first.

Instead of making both call `sem_wait()`, you can initialize the semaphore to `0`, and only let the parent call `sem_wait()`. The child does not wait, but calls `sem_post()` after it is done, which will wake up the parent.

Comment: But how come parent acquires lock before child releases it? It's strange

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Your parent and child are in a race to acquire the semaphore at the same time. This is not what you want. Initialize the semaphore to `0` instead, so that the parent will block waiting on the child. Remove the call to `sem_wait()` from the child.

Comment: I will tell an interesting thing. You know, same code just initializing the semaphore to "0" results in a deadlock. Both parent and child prints: "Waiting to acquire.." and keeps on waiting :-)

Comment: @kingsmasher1: Please read my comment carefully, and pay attention to the highlighted part of my edited answer.

Comment: @jxh this page http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sem_init.html says `If the pshared argument has a non-zero value, then the semaphore is shared between processes; in this case, any process that can access the semaphore sem can use sem for performing sem_wait(), sem_trywait(), sem_post(), and sem_destroy() operations.` which says  shared between processes only when sem is accessible by both, which is not the case here.

Comment: jxh..Oops..no. You know i did exactly the same. Initialized the semaphore to "0" and child does `sem_post`, and removed the `sem_wait` from child. The parent still waits in infinite loop.

Comment: @kingsmasher1: The semaphore also has to be in shared memory.

Comment: @VoidPointer: That's why he said to remove the `sem_wait` from child, and initialize the semaphore value to 0 so that as soon as the child signals, the parent can catch the semaphore. You haven't understood..lol.

Comment: jxh..aah, using mmap that works great, so as suspected the issue was the semaphores not being in shared memory region !! Thanks a ton :-) The strange thing is, only this man page - http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init indicates it to necessarily use shared memory while performing `sem_init`, and not others.

Answer (score 2):

After `fork` parent and child will contain different `sem` variable at entirely different region. Doing `sem_wait(&sem)` will refer entirely different memory in parent and child and thus both are acquiring semaphore.

If you want to semaphore between different processes, then you should use `shared memory` as mentioned in man page of sem_init [here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_init) and the eye opener page [is here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_init.html).

Comment: @jxh (and also at-me!): the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_init.html) page seems rather ambiguous, it can be interpreted as "user must link sem into shared region" or "system will allocate shared region and make something in sem point to this".  Looks like various man pages are less ambiguous.

Comment: @torek: Yeah, I initially had the same gut reaction, but what changed my mind was the "should" be in shared memory. I figured if the manual was specifying how the semaphore would be changed, it would have said "will" be in shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview
A process-shared semaphore must be placed in a shared memory region (e.g., a System V shared memory segment created using shmget(2), or a POSIX shared memory object built created using shm_open(3)).

Comment: @torek: Are you sure. The man page seems to indicate the semaphore should already be in shared memory, and the poster reports behavior like I would expect if the semaphore was not shared (in comments to my answer).

Comment: @torek hi torek .i think his problem due to shared memory . his logic seems right .

Comment: I was poking around in the implementation and thought that it was automatically shared, then I tested and ... it's not.  So I was wrong.